# PyQt auto slots: not called when decorated with a wrapper

Tags: pyqt, signals-slots, python-decorators, pyqt5

I have a `QWidget` created via Qt Designer that has a `QPushButton` named `foo`, and the `QWidget` has a method named `on_foo_clicked`:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_foo_clicked(self):
        pass
```

Firstly, the `on_foo_clicked` is only called if it is decorated with `pyqtSlot()`. If I remove that decorator, I have to manually connect the `self.ui.foo` (of type `QPushButton`) to `self.on_foo_clicked` in `MyWidget`'s initializer, yet I could not find any documentation about this.

Secondly, if I want to use my own decorator like this:

```
def auto_slot(func):
    @pyqtSlot()
    def wrapper(self):
        func(self)
    return wrapper

...

@auto_slot
def on_foo_clicked(self):
    pass
```

it no longer works. But the following works:

```
def auto_slot(func):
    return pyqtSlot()(func)
```

So the issue is not the replacement of `pyqtSlot` by another decorator, but rather that for some reason the `wrapper` function causes the auto connection mechanism to fail. Note that the above issue only affects *automatic* connections; if I add a line in `MyWidget.__init__` to explicitely connect the `self.ui.foo` button to `self.on_foo_clicked`, then the `auto_slot` decorator with `wrapper` works as expected and the method gets called when click button.

Any ideas if there is something I can do to `auto_slot` with `wrapper` so that it will work even with automatically connected slots?

The reason I want this is so that the wrapper can trap exception raised by slot (indication of a bug) and print to console.

Answer (score 1):

Just occurred to me that the problem is that `wrapper` function does not have the right name to be found by the auto connection system. So the following fixes the problem:

```
from functools import wraps
def auto_slot(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self):
        func(self)
    return pyqtSlot()(wrapper)
```